# GDIPlus Headers Emit Warnings When Compiled at Warning Level 4

Tags: c++, gdi+

This problem was raised as a bug to the Microsoft team, however it seems it was closed without any particular fix, (see link below)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2824706/gdi-headers-emit-warnings-when-compiled-at-warning-level-4

In my header file that references gdiplus library, I have used:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4458) // declaration of 'xxx' hides class member
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

This seems to disable the warnings for gdiplus itself, but not for the other libraries referenced by gdiplus, (such as GdiplusImageAttributes for example).

Is there a way to disable those warnings "a level down" to include those libraries?

Comment: I have exactly what you have in order to build at /W4 but I am not seeing any warnings for the 'level down' files. The only difference is I have #include "gdiplus.h" but that should not matter.

Comment: thanks jschroedl.  Well, I am embarrassed to say that one of the pragmas I was using was commented out, hence the warnings...

Comment: np, glad you found it!